# How to restrict overrided property to be read only 

Tags: c#, properties, derived-class, base-class

I am having following code.

```
   class A
    {
        public virtual int BoardSize { get; set; }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override int BoardSize
        {
            get{return 100;}
        }
    }

    Class Client
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.BoardSize = 55;
    }
```

In base class the property is read/write. but in derived class it is readonly and should always return 100. Although when I ran the code I found that it always returns 100 as expected.

But, I don't want client to set BoardSize in B class. So it should not allow client to write **`b.BoardSize = 55`** at all.

How is it possible?

Comment: If the derived classes cannot comply to contract of the base class, then you're misusing inheritance.

Comment: @Martinho, I'd disagree with you that the derived class is not complying with the contract. The contract is being fully honored. The only thing the OP wants is to control the implementation and level of access.

Comment: @code4life, yeah you are absolutely right. As derived class can modify the implementation and this doesn't breaks the rule of inheritance or misuse inheritance.

Comment: @code4life: from what I can see the contract includes a setter for BoardSize. If the derived class doesn't have one, I call that a breach of contract.

Comment: @anil: Sure, derived classes can modify the implementation. But from what I understand you don't want to *modify implementation*, you want to *modify the interface* (removing a setter).

Comment: @Martinho, I would disagree with your very strict definition of a contract. Take a look at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract. There are many opinions on contracts, some very strict, some very loose. Taking the strictest approach is not necessarily the canonical way.

Comment: BTW, you say overridden, not overrided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Throw an exception in the setter:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int BoardSize { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
  public override int BoardSize
  {
    get { return 100; }
    set {
      throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot set BoardSize on class B.");
    }
  }
}
```

If your code has a path where it may try to set `BoardSize` on an instance of `B` you should be prepared to handle that exception.

2) Only allow the derived class to set `BoardSize`:

```
class A
{
  public int BoardSize { get; protected set; }
}

class B : A
{
  public B()
  {
    BoardSize = 100;
  }
}

class C : A
{
  public void SetBoardSize(int boardSize)
  {
    BoardSize = boardSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to throw, `NotSupportedException` is more appropriate. InvalidOperation is for "when a method call is invalid for the object's current state." Since it does not depend on current state at all, I'd prefer NotSupported.

Comment: @Marthinho Fernandes: I guess you are right. I was thinking along the lines that a reference to `A` being an instance of `B` was invalid "state" for setting `BoardSize`.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Well... you can't!
Long answer:
You can hide the implementation of `BoardSize` from the base class using `new`:

```
class B : A
{
    public new int BoardSize
    {
        get{return 100;}
    }
}
```

This will make the following code invalid:

```
B b = new B();
b.BoardSize = 55;
```

But this will only make matters worse!
The following code IS valid:

```
A a = new B();
a.BoardSize = 55;
Console.WriteLine(a.BoardSize);
Console.WriteLine(((B)a).BoardSize);
```

and it prints

> 55
>   100

Conclusion:
You could use `new` to achieve your goal, but this will introduce serious problems in your code.
If you can't change `A` and `B` needs to derive from `A` then use this code:

```
class B : A
{
    public override int BoardSize
    {
        get{return 100;}
        set{throw new NotSupportedException();}
    }
}
```

This is consistent to the .NET framework. For example, `ReadOnlyCollection` throws this exception when you call `Add` (after casting it to `ICollection<T>`).

Comment: I removed what I think was a superfluous "new" in the last sample, otherwise it would share the issues with the first one. Hope that's what you intended.

Comment: @Martinho: Yes, I forgot to change the `new` to `override`. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Best answer here I think, covers the best options available with issues that may arise.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a **new** property in B that hides the one in A:

```
class B : A
{
    public new int BoardSize
    {
        get{return 100};
    }
}
```

Comment: If you access `BoardSize` of an instance of `B` via a reference to `A` you get `0` and not `100`. Most likely not what is wanted when creating a virtual property.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int BoardSize { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: From the msdn "A protected member is accessible from within the class in which it is declared, and from within any class derived from the class that declared this member" so I doubt this will work.

Comment: "But, I don't want client to set BoardSize in B class. So it should not allow client to write b.BoardSize = 55 at all." I assume with the virtual keyword, and inheritance as listed that he still wants to set the property from within the B class, just not from an external instance of B. Protecting the set accessor does this.

Comment: @Andy: it does make the code sample non-compilable, so I guess this might work.

Comment: That won't do it. You should use the **new** keyword and control access from there.

Comment: new would throw away the virtual term, which I can only assume was intended. The question is worded a little awkwardly.

Comment: @Martinho - yes it does but it also means that the client cannot set this property on the base class type either which according to the question should remain read/writable.

Comment: @Andy - that's a fair point, I wonder what the @anil is trying to accomplish here, and if there is a better way. Of course as otheres have pointed out, you will get some strange results setting the base class's property and then reading the derived with the new keyword.

Comment: @asawyer, it will throw error as you cannot modify access modifier in derived class if you are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

If it may be necessary for a derived class to change an outward-facing aspect of a member (e.g. change a property between read/write and read-only, or have a method in a derived-type return a more-derived type than a like-named method in the base type), then the member itself should be non-virtual, but its implementation should simply wrap a call to a protected virtual implementation.  Derived types may shadow the base class's members that call the protected virtual implementation, but should not put meaningful logic there.

Thus:

```
class A
{
    public int BoardSize { get {return GetBoardSize(); set {SetBoardSize(value); }
    protected abstract int GetBoardSize();
    protected abstract void SetBoardSize(int newSize);
    public abstract bool IsResizable { get; }
}

class B : A
{
    public new int BoardSize { get {return GetBoardSize(); }
    protected override int GetBoardSize() { return 100; }
    protected override void SetBoardSize(int newSize)
        { throw new NotSupportedException("Board is not resizable."); }
    public override bool IsResizable { get {return false;} }
}
```

An attempt to set `BoardSize` on a variable of type `B` will fail at compile time on the basis that the property is read-only.  Storing a reference to a `B` in a variable of type `A` and trying to set BoardSize on that will compile, but will throw an exception at runtime.  The class should be documented to specify that code which wants to set `BoardSize` should be prepared for the fact that the board may not be resizable, and that if the caller code would be able to do something sensible in that case, it should check `IsResizable` before trying to set `BoardSize`.